# It say missing dependencies in package json

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

[this is the error message that shows when i try to install react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8c8R.png)  I'm setting up a new project for react, and when I try to `npm install create-react-app` it shows error like missing dependencies in `package.json`.

```
npm install create-react-app

npm install create-react-app my-app
```

I expected that the dependencies should be added inside my package.json but nothing appers.

Comment: Look at the info you give us and ask yourself.... "is the person who likes to help me able to reproduce anything I mention here...."? Don't we need somethings like system, version, subversion numbers... how you you did install anything else that might be related to the problem.... error-logs....

Comment: Your title is very generic. People will skip over your question this way. A better title might have been 'Missing dependencies error when trying to install create-react-app'.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed npm 5.2+, you can just use `npx` to execute node packages, or you need to install create-react-app globally to make it executable globally.

**npm version**

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
```

**npx version**

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: i have tried for that also npm i -g create-react-app